# Insert a value in a specific line by index

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

```
private void Parse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keywordRanks.Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        int p = keywordRanks.Lines.Length;
        MessageBox.Show(p.ToString());

        string splitString = keywordRanks.Lines[i];
        string[] s = splitString.Split(':');

        for (int j = 0; j < keywords.Lines.Length; j++)
        {
            string searchString = keywords.Lines[j];

            if (s[0].Equals(searchString))
            {
               richTextBox1.Lines[j] = searchString + ':' + s[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an issue with inserting string in a particular line. I have 2 multi line TextBoxes and one RichTextBox.
My application will search for the strings from `textbox1` to `textbox2` line by line and need to insert those matched values in a RichTextBox control but in the exact index position where it found in `textbox2`.

If the value found in 5th line of `textbox2` then that found line need to be inserted in the RichTextBox 5th line.
Some how my code is not working. I tried a lot but no luck. The code I need something like below but its not working and an `IndexOutOfBound` exception is raised.

```
richTextBox1.Lines[j] = searchString + ':' + s[1];
```

Comment: does the `multiline` property of the text box control is set to true and a newline character appears in the text?

Comment: Yes multiline property is true. My code working fine until it matches the line in textbox2 (I tested it with message box ) but in order to insert that found string in richtextbox editor, at the same index where it was found in textbox2. Here the error came into picture.

Comment: you will get IndexOutOfRangeException because you are iterating over `keywords.Lines.Length`, but doing `richTextBox1.Lines[j]` , which might have less lines then keywords

Comment: There no way for that. Even I tried the below lines its retuning values in message box but not inserting not sure why. MessageBox.Show(richTextBox1.Lines[2]);
                richTextBox1.Lines[2].Insert(2, "123");

Comment: Can you provide some sample input?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BRyDi7ud @NathanWerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RichTextBox` must contain all the needed lines before you can set the value using the line index.
If the Control contains no text or line breaks (`\n`), no lines are defined and any attempt to set a specific `Line[Index]` value will generate an `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception.

Here, I'm using a pre-built array, sized as the number of possible matches (the `Lines.Length`  of the `keywords` TextBox). All matches found are stored here in the original position. The array is then assigned to the `RichTextBox.Lines` property.

**Note**: directly using and pre-setting the `RichTextBox.Lines` won't have effect: the text will remain empty.

```
string[] MatchesFound = new string[keywords.Lines.Length];
foreach (string currentSourceLine in keywordRanks.Lines)
{
    string[] SourceLineValue = currentSourceLine.Split(':');

    var match = keywords.Lines.ToList().FindIndex(s => s.Equals(SourceLineValue[0]));
    if (match > -1)
        MatchesFound[match] = currentSourceLine;
}
richTextBox1.Lines = MatchesFound;
```

---

```
     Source        Matches         Result
  (keywordRanks)  (keywords)    (RichTextBox)
  -------------------------------------------
     aand:1         aand           aand:1
     cnd:5          this one      
     cnds:9         cnds           cnds:9
     fan:2          another one   
     gst:0          cnd            cnd:5
                    fan            fan:2
```

Comment: Thank you really appreciate. I will check on this tomorrow.